# ManyToMany annotations not generating join in select query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

**Summary**:
I'm trying to build & eagerly retrieve a unidirectional ManyToMany relationship using jpa + hibernate.

When doing a findAll(), the referenced entities are empty, when there should be 1.

The SQL that hibernate is generating (using show-sql property) is missing the join from what I see.

**Context**:

- Spring Data - 4.0.4.RELEASE
- Hibernate - 4.2.21.Final

Some alternatives / fixes I have tried:

- Have tried switching them to a OneToMany/ManyToOne Relationship.
- Have tried setting up a bidirectional ManyToMany relationship by referencing Class from Student using mappedBy
- Have tried updating Class's id column to not be different in the join table

**Java entities**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Column(name = "student_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class")
public class Class {

@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "class_student",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id"))
    private Set<Student> students;
```

**DDL**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
    student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id `)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class_student ` (
    student_id INT NOT NULL,
    class_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id `, `class_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_student_id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_class_id` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`)
);
```

**Actual vs Expected**:
The actual generated sql when I `classRespository.getAll()` seems to be missing the join between class + class_student that I would expect.

It also oddly includes a join between student and class_student that I would not expect, given that it's unidirectionally defined and I don't know what is being done with the results of that unexpected query besides likely being discarded.

**Actual generated SQL** :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        classin0_.id as id1_29_,
    from
        class classin0_
    INNER JOIN
       post_tag pt
    ON     p.id = pt.post_id
    INNER JOIN
        tag t
    ON     pt.tag_id = t.id
    WHERE  p.id = 1
Hibernate: 
    select
        class_student0_.class_id as id1_30_1_,
        class_student0_.student_id as featured2_10_1_,
        student1_.student_id as featured1_28_0_,
    from
        class_student class_student0_ 
    inner join
        student student1_ 
            on class_student0_.student_id=student1_.student_id 
    where
        class_student0_.id=?
```

I would expect a query with inner joins across the three tables that jpa can parse back into a Set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just as a FYI, eagerly fetching a ManyToMany is usually a bad idea, as it can end up in a lot of duplication is the returned data.

Comment: A side note - don't name a class `Class`, come up with something like `Lecture` or something. Otherwise that might cause many problems.

Comment: @sp00m is it better to treat it as a ManyToOne then?

Comment: @Amongalen oh agreed, just a (poor) temp name for the question, it's not a students - class relationship in reality

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your mapping — it is correct. I was using these classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Column(name = "student_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Class")
public class Class {

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "className")
    private String className;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "class_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id"))
    private Set<Student> students;

}
```

> The actual generated sql when I classRespository.getAll() seems to be missing the join between class + class_student that I would expect. It also oddly includes a join between student and class_student that I would not expect

Hibernate doesn't use join for `class` and `class_student` relation.

Hibernate gets all classes by the first query

```
select
    class0_.id as id1_0_,
    class0_.className as classNam2_0_ 
from
    Class class0_
```

And after that gets all students for the one existing class using `inner join` between `class_student` and `student`.

```
   select
        students0_.class_id as class_id1_1_0_,
        students0_.student_id as student_2_1_0_,
        student1_.student_id as student_1_2_1_,
        student1_.name as name2_2_1_ 
    from
        class_student students0_ 
    inner join
        student student1_ 
            on students0_.student_id=student1_.student_id 
    where
        students0_.class_id=?
```

I can't check your SQL, because it is incorrect.
For example there is not such field `class_student0_.id=?` in the `class_student` table.

Comment: Sorry, the `id` should have been `class_id` in the join table.

Comment: @GavinFitzgerald Better to provide real SQL or do testing with `Class`, `Student` entities.